# Generic object "watcher" proxy to wrap collection objects to log state-changes (add/del)

Tags: python, logging, collections, proxy, trace

I want to add "watchers" to some variables used by a library.
They are of type `collections.deque`, `dict`, `weakref.WeakSet`,
and `list`.

Anytime that an item is added/appended or popped to/from them I'd like to generate
a log message.

I'd like to minimize the changes to the original code:

- I don't want to add log messages in all of the places where the
  variables are accessed and modified.
- I don't want to create my own classes that inherit from the original
  classes (e.g. `class InstrumentedDeque(collections.deque): ...`)

Instead, and this is the question, is it possible to create a single
generic class (or wrapper/decorator) that works for all of the collection
objects above, so that the only place where changes are needed is where
the objects are originally created. If this is the original code, with 2
vars to "watch": `self.scheduled` and `self.ready`...

```
def __init__(self):
    self.scheduled = []
    self.ready = collections.deque()
```

then the only changes required would be something like...

```
def __init__(self):
    self.scheduled = MyLogger([], var_name='scheduled')
    self.ready = MyLogger(collections.deque(), var_name='ready')
```

## without instrumentation

```
test = Test()

test.add(1)
test.add(2)
test.pop()
```

## after instrumentation changes

```
test = Test()

test.add(1)
***instrumentation output. scheduled: [1]
***instrumentation output. ready: deque([1])

test.add(2)
***instrumentation output. scheduled: [1, 2]
***instrumentation output. ready = deque([1, 2])

test.pop()
***instrumentation output. scheduled: [2]
***instrumentation output. ready: deque([2])
```

where the example `add()` and `pop()` would look something like this...

```
    def add(self, val):
        heapq.heappush(self.scheduled, val)
        self.ready.append(val)

    def pop(self):
        heapq.heappop(self.scheduled)
        self.ready.popleft()
```

I've tried creating a "wrapper" class and played with
`__new__`, `__init__`, `__getattr__` but haven't been able
to get this to work. Something like this...

```
class MyLooger:
    def __new__(cls):
        # what to do?

    def __init__(self):
        # what to do?

    def __getattr__(self, name):
        # what to do?
```

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Note:** the following abstraction *does not* work with C extension code that goes directly into the low-level internals of the wrapped object (such as `heapq.heappush`, both on CPython as well as PyPy); there's nothing that can be done to alleviate that at the Python level. You *might* see if you can "patch the leak" at the C level, but then you'll have to get your hands dirty with writing C and a Python extension.

**Solution:** You don't need to go as far as `__new__`. The following will work generically on all objects. It will also make `isinstance` work on the wrapper as if it were called on the wrapped object.

```
from functools import wraps

class Logged(object):
    def __init__(self, obj, obj_name):
        self.obj = obj
        self.obj_name = obj_name

    def __getattribute__(self, attr_name):
        obj = object.__getattribute__(self, 'obj')
        obj_name = object.__getattribute__(self, 'obj_name')

        attr = getattr(obj, attr_name)
        # this is not 100% generic, mathematically speaking,
        # but covers all methods and the `__class__` attribute:
        if not callable(attr) or isinstance(attr, type):
            return attr

        @wraps(attr)
        def fn(*args, **kwargs):
            print "%s called on %s with: %s and %s" % (attr_name, obj_name, args, kwargs)
            return attr(*args, **kwargs)

        return fn

    def __repr__(self):
        return repr(object.__getattribute__(self, 'obj'))
```

And then just:

```
>>> scheduled = Logged([], obj_name="scheduled")

>>> scheduled.append
<function append>

>>> scheduled.append(3)
append called on scheduled with: (3,) and {}

>>> scheduled.extend([1,2])
extend called on scheduled with: ([1, 2],) and {}

>>> isinstance(scheduled, list)
True

>>> scheduled
[3, 1, 2]
```

Comment: I think, you have forgotten `.add`

Comment: @ErikAllik re missing `.add`: I think, your first version was overriding method `add` and in your override you have forgotten calling the original add method after logging step. But this is irrelevant with your strongly updated answer.

Comment: this is really close and great @erik.  It works for all cases, _except_ for the self.scheduled case in my original example, which is actually updated via heapq.heappush/heappop. As you warn in you answer, these are probably making use of isinstance which results in an exception: "TypeError: heap argument must be a list".  I want to use this instrumentation on the new python3.4 asyncio code, which makes use of heapq to update the _scheduled list. I tried overriding  \__new__() to try to make Logged return a new object that also inherits from the "watched" class but haven't made it work.

Comment: @jd. OK, finally the code works as advertised! :) I've even added `__repr__` as a bonus so the object even looks like the underlying object when printed!

Comment: @ErikAllik keeps getting better - thanks. Other than the "TypeError: heap argument must be a list" for the self.scheduled case, it's really close. Again, I'll wait to see if there is a solution that can take care of the isintance issue (somehow make the class being watched - be included in the __mro__ of the Logged object).

Comment: If you call `isinstance(scheduled, list)` on the object, does it return `True`? If yes and the heapq thing still doesn't work, it means you are out of luck — `heapq` must be using some lower level access to the object which bypasses `__getattribute__`. There is no way to fix this other than possibly going down to the C level. Basically you're hitting what is known as a "Leaky Abstraction" — all (or at least most) abstractions are inherently leaky, and there's nothing much you can do about it in real life.

Comment: For example, on PyPy, `heapq.heappush(scheduled, 3)` fails instead with `TypeError: 'Logged' has no length` — again, magic is leaky, and you can't do much about it other than avoid it altogether.

Comment: @erik - Agree. Trying to satisfy heapq's specific check of the underlying object's class is just beyond reasonable for what I originally asked (isinstance(test.scheduled, list) does return True).  Thanks for all your help. Great answer! (Although, I still think that things may work by adjusting Logged's __mro__ :)

Comment: Let me know if hacking on `mro` gets you anywhere — I'd be curious to know! Don't have more energy to tinker on this for now though. It's not like there's tons of upvotes flowing in or smth :P